# Execute local shell script using docker run interactive

Tags: docker

Can I execute a local shell script within a docker container using `docker run -it` ?

Here is what I can do:

```
$ docker run -it 5ee0b7440be5                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
bash-4.2# echo "Hello"
Hello
bash-4.2# exit
exit
```

I have a shell script on my local machine

hello.sh:

```
echo "Hello"
```

I would like to execute the local shell script within the container and read the value returned:

```
$ docker run -it 5e3337440be5 #Some way of passing a reference to hello.sh to the container.
Hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to mount a local file to the container and execute it. When you do that, however, be aware that you'll need to be providing the container process with write/execute access to the folder or specific script you want to run. Depending on your objective, using Docker for this purpose may not be the best idea.
See [@David Maze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68483360/4676641) for reasons why. However, here's how you can do it:

Assuming you're on a Unix based system and the `hello.sh` script is in your current directory, you can mount that single script to the container with `-v $(pwd)/hello.sh:/home/hello.sh`.

This command will mount the file to your container, start your shell in the folder where you mounted it, and run a shell:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd)/hello.sh:/home/hello.sh --workdir /home ubuntu:20.04 /bin/sh

root@987eb876b:/home ./hello.sh
Hello World!
```

This command will run that script directly and save the output into the variable `output`:

```
output=$(docker run -it -v $(pwd)/hello.sh:/home/test.sh ubuntu:20.04 /home/hello.sh)

echo $output
Hello World!
```

References for more information:

- https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#use-a-read-only-bind-mount

Comment: Thanks, my use-case is just to determine the java version installed in the images. This works great.

Answer (score 1):

A specific design goal of Docker is that you *can't*.  A container can't access the host filesystem at all, except to the extent that an administrator explicitly mounts parts of the filesystem into the container.  (See [@tentative's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68479116/10008173) for a way to do this for your use case.)

In most cases this means you need to `COPY` all of the scripts and support tools into your image.  You can create a container running any command you want, and one typical approach is to set the image's `CMD` to do "the normal thing the container will normally do" (like run a Web server) but to allow running the container with a different command (an admin task, a background worker, ...).

```sh
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine
...
COPY hello.sh /usr/local/bin
...
EXPOSE 80
CMD httpd -f -h /var/www
```

```sh
docker build -t my/image .
docker run -d -p 8000:80 --name web my/image
docker run --rm --name hello my/image \
  hello.sh
```

In normal operation you should not need `docker exec`, though it's really useful for debugging.  If you are in a situation where you're really stuck, you need more diagnostic tools to be understand how to reproduce a situation, and you don't have a choice but to look inside the running container, you can also [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) the script or tool into the container before you `docker exec` there.  If you do this, remember that the image also needs to contain any dependencies for the tool (interpreters like Python or GNU Bash, C shared libraries), and that any `docker cp`d files will be lost when the container exits.